# Unused argument in K Means

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I would like to do a cluster analysis with Kmeans and use the Euclidean distance.

This is part of my code:

```
WKA_ohneJB <- read.csv("WKA_ohneJB.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

WKA_ohneJB_scaled <- scale(WKA_ohneJB)

set.seed (123)

WKA_ohneJB_sample <- sample(1:500, 300) 

WKA_ohneJB_scaled <- WKA_ohneJB_scaled[WKA_ohneJB_sample,]
kmeans(WKA_ohneJB_scaled, 8, iter.max = 10, nstart = 1, method = "euclidean")

fviz_nbclust(WKA_ohneJB_scaled, kmeans, method = "wss")+ geom_vline(xintercept = 8, linetype = 2)
```

> Error in kmeans(WKA_ohneJB_scaled, 8, iter.max = 10, nstart = 1,
>   method = "euclidean") :   ununsed argument (method = "euclidean")

[image]

Comment: From the documentation it seems that `kmeans()` does not have an argument `method`; you should leave it out. By default, `kmeans()` uses the squared Euclidean distance between cluster centers and elements. I am not sure if you can use the standard Euclidean distance instead (and I don't think so).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the "amap" package to be able to use the "Kmeans" (with capital K) function which is different from the "kmeans" function.

Here's the link to the documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/amap/versions/0.8-18/topics/Kmeans